# ReactJS setState not working on first toggle of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Is there a reason `setState` would not be running to rerender? I've used a `console.log` callback to detect if the state has changed, but to no avail.

Here is the code I'm using. There's more such that the state is a `bool` for a function call, but the basics of the function is here.

```
export class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
    this.state = {
      usingToggleOne: false
    };
  }
}
toggleforToggleOne(event) {
  this.setState({
    usingToggleOne: !this.state.usingToggleOne,
  }); 
}

render() {
  return(
    <input type="checkbox"
                   onChange={this.toggleforToggleOne.bind(this)} />
}
```

I'll hit the checkbox the first time and it will tick, but the state doesn't change, but after it'll work normally. Any reasons why? I've had luck using `Object.assign` to get the first tick to work, but I'd rather not use that because it's mutating the state.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try `console.log()` in the `render()` or in the `componentDidUpdate()` methods as demonstrated in the code below and in this codepen: http://codepen.io/PiotrBerebecki/pen/ZpLNZd 
You can also **access new state using the optional callback function passed to 'setState'**. More info here: http://reactkungfu.com/2016/03/dive-into-react-codebase-handling-state-changes/#solving_the_validation_problem

The state `bool` changes each time the box is ticked / unticked.

Also, please note the following from the React docs: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate

> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.
>   setState() will always trigger a re-render unless conditional rendering logic is implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(). If mutable objects are being used and the logic cannot be implemented in shouldComponentUpdate(), calling setState() only when the new state differs from the previous state will avoid unnecessary re-renders.

```
class ExampleClass extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      usingToggleOne: false
    };

  }

  toggleforToggleOne(event) {
    console.clear();
    console.log('check in toggle before set state', this.state.usingToggleOne);
    this.setState({
      usingToggleOne: !this.state.usingToggleOne
    }, function afterStateChange () {this.useNewState();});
    console.log('check in toggle after set state', this.state.usingToggleOne);
  }

  useNewState() {
    console.log('check in useNewState callback', this.state.usingToggleOne);
  }

  componentWillUpdate() {
    console.log('check in componentWillUpdate', this.state.usingToggleOne);
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log('check in componentDidUpdate', this.state.usingToggleOne);
  }

  render() {
    console.log('check in render', this.state.usingToggleOne);
    return(
      <input type="checkbox"
             onChange={this.toggleforToggleOne.bind(this)} />
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting! So I called it in render and it's returning the correct state, but I'm also calling the state before render, in `componentWillUpdate` and in there I'm getting the incorrect state.

Comment: Well spotted! I've added further information to my answer to explain this.

Comment: ohh okay that makes a lot more sense as to why there is the issue.
I'm looking into this more, it seems `LinkedStateMixin` is the solution. Thanks :)

EDIT: seems it's already deprecated, I guess two-way binding?

Comment: I've updated my answer (and codepen) to show that the state change can be observed in `componentDidUpdate`. Does this answer now clears this for you?

Comment: It does a lot! I've been having trouble just even diagnosing the problem. Is two-way binding the best solution to use the state value immediately?

Comment: NEVERMIND. SOLVED WITH `componentDidUpdate`

Comment: I've added further information.  You can also access new state using an optional callback function passed to `setState()`.